# Как вписать текст в прямоугольник правильно SVG?

Tags: svg

Нужна подсказка, почему смещение текста в блоках `<tspan>` происходит не так как ожидалось? А именно координаты на втором `<tspan>` нужно увеличивать?

Ну и у знающих людей правильно ли я делаю, или есть еще какие-то более продуманные решения для реализации такого вида картинки?

P.S.  Длинна текста может меняться, в различных блоках. Как бы можно было бы так сделать, чтобы автоматически вычислялось позиционирование?

```html
<svg>
    <g id="infoTable${settings.SVGindex}">
        <rect class='map' x="0" y="0" width="135" height="80" fill="red" font-family="Verdana" font-size="14px" rx="10" ry="10" />
        <text dx="67.5" dy="20" fill="blue" font-size="1rem" text-anchor="middle">
            SET, FEBR 24
        </text>
        <text dx="10" dy="40" font-size=".9rem" fill="blue">
            <tspan x="5" y="0">
                1352
            </tspan>
            <tspan x="5" dy="20">
                Joined
            </tspan>
        </text>
        <text dx="50" dy="40" font-size=".9rem" fill="blue">
            <tspan x="30" y="0">
                60
            </tspan>
            <tspan x="80" dy="20">
                Left
            </tspan>
        </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: `почему смещение текста в блоках <tspan> происходит не так как ожидалось?`  --- А как ожидалось? Правь вопрос, опиши подробнее конечный желаемый результат...

Comment: я ожидаю что относительно rect будут отсчитываться координаты dx dy,  а tspan от родительского текста. а пришлось абсолютные координаты использовать.

Comment: @dpi, автоматически никак

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject  если только это ..и то под сомнением

Comment: @dpi, Павел хорошую ссылку предложил. Мой (исправленный совсем недавно) ответ основан именно на [этом элементе](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Элемент/foreignObject).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробовал MDN-примочки в деле:

```css
svg { width: 100%; } 
#par { width: 360px; height: 50%; padding: 6px; color: #ddd; 
       overflow: auto; border-radius: 6px; background: rgba(0,0,0,.6); }
#abza { width: 320px; padding: 6px; color: #266; border-radius: 6px; background: rgba(240, 220, 200, .8); }
#abz { width: 320px; padding: 6px; color: #822; border-radius: 6px; background: rgba(240, 240, 240, .8); }
#re {fill: #acc;}
polygon { fill: #088; }
#coda {x:50px; y:240px; width:340px; height:160px; padding: 6px; 
       border-radius: 6px; background: rgba(140, 140, 140, .8);}
```

```html
<!-- Узнайте об этом коде на MDN: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Элемент/foreignObject -->

<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <polygon points="2,2 440,10 400,210 10,200" />
  <!-- Типичный пример использования: встраивание HTML-текста в SVG -->
  <foreignObject x="20" y="10" width="400" height="300">
  <!-- В контексте SVG, внедренного в HTML, пространство имен XHTML может и следует избегать, 
       но это обязательно в контексте документа SVG -->
    <div id="par" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <p id="abza"><i>
      - Делись, хозяин, научи меня "стяжать",<br>
      - Пались, как "лоха" объегоривать умело,<br>
      И как на кол, взамен себя - других сажать,<br>
      Но чтобы выглядело - будто бы "за дело"...<br>
      </i></p><i>
      Как, скорбь не имав, но ходить по головам,<br>
      А подвернётся некий случай - и по трупам,<br>
      И как суметь, придаша вес пустым словам -<br>
      Буровить головы слепцов, аки шурупом...<br></i>
      <p id="abz">
      - Нет, всё не так, да и зачем перечислять...<br>
      Един в трёх лицах он, "Хозяин-мегаполис",<br>
      Его богатство, слава, власть и "реки вспять",<br>
      Ещё - "идея", чтобы знать, "за что боролись".<br>
      </p><i>
      За сим - не дрейфь, доход разделим пополам,<br>
      Накрыв иных - пусть деревянным, но прибором,<br>
      Восславив - "Сейф",... - И да прогнётся Валаам<br>
      И разнесёт ту весть по всем святым соборам...</i>
      <p id="abz">
      Решил слукавить на святынях? - Перебор...<br>
      Лугов и пастбищ - зря хозяина порочишь,<br>
      Тайги владельца, рек, полей, высоких гор,<br>
      Он - мой. - Лепи своих, какими хочешь...
      </p>
    </div>
  </foreignObject>
  <rect id="re" x="20" y="220" width="400" height="200" rx="10"></rect> 
    <foreignObject id="coda">
    <p id="abz">
      - Смолчал хозяин, да и то, что мог сказать<br>
      - Мне невдомёк, но во владениях чертога<br>
      Поможет дом срубить да судьбы вам связать.<br>
      Не веришь ежли - испроси у Бога...
    </p>
    <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Элемент/foreignObject" 
       target="_blank">Узнайте об этом коде на MDN:</a>
    </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Пришлось поправить предыдущий ответ, в котором было много ошибок.
Полагаю, что сейчас стало гораздо наглядней.
[Песочница:](https://codepen.io/warsan/pen/JzwoWp)

Comment: Он получается к ширине подстраивается? Круто.

Comment: Дмитрий Полянин,  Это благодаря строке: svg { width: 100%;}